# VIM: how to update text when saving

Tags: vim, configuration, header, editor

I'm trying to get into the habit of using one editor (gVim 7.3 on Windows XP) for all programming and development tasks.

I'd like to update a header in any open file when I save using :w

The header looks like this (in a C file):

```
/* Filename: hello.c
 * Filesize: 345 bytes
 * Last Modified: Fri Feb 25, 2011  01:55PM
 */
```

I actually already figured out how to update Last Modified, by including the following in my _vimrc file:

```
" If buffer modified, update any 'Last modified: ' in the first 20 lines.
" 'Last modified: ' can have up to 10 characters before (they are retained).
" Restores cursor and window position using save_cursor variable.
function! LastModified()
  if &modified
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let n = min([20, line("$")])
    keepjumps exe '1,' . n . 's#^\(.\{,10}Last Modified:\).*#\1' .
          \ strftime(' %a %b %d, %Y  %I:%M%p') . '#e'
    call histdel('search', -1)
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
  endif
endfun

autocmd BufWritePre * call LastModified()
```

My question is, using a similar approach, how can I have Filename and Filesize update as well?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do this at all? Your version control system stores the same information, so you're just manually duplicating what gets automatically saved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the current file name using `@%`:

```
keepjumps exe '1,' . n . 's#^\(.\{,10}Filename:\).*#\1' .
      \ ' ' . @% . '#e'
```

No idea about the file size, though.

Not to mention that you will actually be modifying the file size by adding the file size, so it may be impossible to get right.

Comment: And of course, we all want to know: why on earth to you want to do this?

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. If anyone knows about the filesize it would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you could programmatically yank the whole file and then use `strlen(@")` (or whatever register you yanked into), provided that there is a one-to-one mapping between characters and bytes in your encoding/content. Again, note that by writing the file size in the file itself, you *may be changing the file size*, making the value you just inserted instantly obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do it at all.**

Your version control system stores the same information. If you're not using one, start.

Comment: In this case, even the *file system* stores the same information.

Comment: Not only is the information already stored elsewhere, but you potentially make it harder to version control by storing this in the file. (Imagine trying to merge...)